# Installation issue in: 'react-native-tab-view'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Main Error**

"Couldn't find any versions for "react-native-background-geolocation-android" that matches "2.7.1" "

**Environment**

- OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.5
- Node: 6.11.0
- Yarn: 1.0.2
- npm: 5.3.0
- Watchman: 4.9.0
- Xcode: Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

**Steps to Reproduce**

I was trying to add the react-native-tab-view library in one of my existing project. So I did:

> yarn add react-native-tab-view

inside my project directory.

**Expected Behavior**

The library should get installed/Add in my project.

**Actual Behavior**

It threw an unexpected error:

```
yarn add react-native-tab-view
yarn add v1.0.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]  Resolving packages...
warning polyline@0.2.0: This module is now under the @mapboxnamespace: install instead
warning connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
warning node-uuid@1.4.7: Use uuid module instead
Couldn't find any versions for "react-native-background-geolocation-android" that matches "2.7.1"
? Please choose a version of "react-native-background-geolocation-android" from
this list: (Use arrow keys)
❯ 0.0.1-security
```

Screenshot 1:
[image]

**Furthur**

If I proceed by selecting the '0.0.1-security', I get an error in the installation.

Screenshot 2:
[image]

Get full error log: [click here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/350)

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MyAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "babel js/ -d lib/",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "flow": "node_modules/.bin/flow",
    "flow start": "flow start",
    "flow stop": "flow stop",
    "flow status": "flow status",
    "flow coverage": "flow coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.2.0",
    "polyline": "^0.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "4.1.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-appsee": "^2.3.32",
    "react-native-background-geolocation-android": "2.7.1",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.17.3-beta",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-file-transfer-android": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.13.1",
    "react-native-message-composer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-newrelic": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0",
    "react-native-slack-webhook": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-sms-x": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^0.0.69",
    "react-native-uploader": "0.0.10",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.10.2",
    "redux-persist": "^4.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.2",
    "flow-bin": "^0.37.0",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "npm": "^4.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your `package.json` file please

Comment: @bennygenel added now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you explicitly selected `react-native-background-geolocation-android`'s version to `2.7.1`?

There is no release with the version number `2.7.1` on that library. If you change it to `2.7.0` or a newer version of the library and then run the command `yarn add react-native-tab-view` it will be installed.

You can find the release numbers of `react-native-background-geolocation-android` [here](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/releases)

Comment: I updated to changed the version in package.json file to '2.9.3' (latest) and '2.7.0'. And both time I got the same issue: 


Couldn't find any versions for "react-native-background-geolocation-android" that matches "2.9.3"
? Please choose a version of "react-native-background-geolocation-android" from 
this list: 
❯ 0.0.1-security

Comment: Could you try to delete `node_modules` folder and lock files and try to do a clean install please